# how to make letter "s" equals to letter "z" in input prompt in javascript in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, alert, prompt

i want to make the word brazil the same as brasil in this prompt

```
      let country1 = "Brazil",
        country2 = "Portugal";

      if (
        country.toLowerCase() === country1.toLowerCase() ||
        country.toLowerCase() === country2.toLowerCase()
      ) {
        alert("You speak Portugese.");
      } else {
        alert("You don't speak Portugese!");
      }
```

how can i make s and z equals?

the alert "You can speak Portugese" will be display if "brasil" or "brazil" will be inputted.

Comment: you should make it so `if ($userInput == "brasil"){ $userInput = "brazil"}` and u can read the data as you want, and filter all possible inputs
and even shorter : `userInput = (userInput === "brasil") ? "brazil" : userInput;`

Answer (score 0):

This requirement is usually called “input sanitizing”. It means you take what you’ve got from the user and change it in such a way that it suits your needs. Upper-casing strings, removing excess whitespace, things like that.

In your case you could prepend a line `country1 = country1.replace('razil', 'rasil');` and similar for country2 in front of the test. Then you only have to deal with a single spelling later.